# Université des finances près le gouvernement russe

Tags: traduction, prépositions, noms, administration

Il semble que l'[Université des finances du gouvernement russe](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universit%C3%A9_des_finances_du_gouvernement_russe) ait choisi pour nom français (un exemple [ici](http://www.franfinco.cf/)) :

> Université des finances **près le** gouvernement russe

Cette aberration grammaticale me paraît difficilement défendable, mais je pense qu'il s'agit d'une abbréviation pour *présidée*. Le sujet serait alors inversé !

Si on s'en tient [au nom anglais](http://international.fa.ru/Pages/Home.aspx), le vrai nom deviendrait :

> Université des finances **prés. par** le gouvernement de Russie

Ai-je raté quelque chose ou quelqu'un pourrait-il éclairer ma lanterne ?

Comment: a priori ça n’apparaît sur rien d'officiel de chez eux donc cette traduction erronée pourrait très bien provenir d'un journaliste ou de quelqu'un d'externe a l'institution. Pourquoi d'ailleurs une université Russe se devrait-elle de se choisir également un nom Français? Le nom Russe est "Finansovyy universitet pri Pravitelstve Rossiyskoy Federatsii", ce qui est un peut different de "pres le gouvernement russe". Rien ne dit que cette traduction maladroite soit leur traduction officielle... citer wikipedia, c'es toujours risque...

Comment: @KarlZorn Je connais des étudiants qui y sont et qui me disent que les documents traduits en français ont ce nom d'université.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Le mot *près* est ici une préposition ([TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/pr%C3%A8s) A.2). Ce n'est pas une aberration, mais une tournure vieillie. De nos jours, elle n'est guère employée que dans des tournures administratives (« expert près la cour d'appel de Paris », « ambassadeur de France près le Saint-Siège », …). En français courant, on dirait « auprès de ».

La traduction me semble ici un contresens, puisque *près X* est normalement utilisé pour une personne ou une institution indépendante de X dont le rôle est d'interagir avec X. Il ne convient pas à une institution sous le contrôle de X. Ce n'est pas le seul aspect étrange de cette traduction : le mot « finances » au pluriel ne désigne pas le domaine du savoir qu'est la finance, mais la gestion financière d'une entité en particulier, donc une « université des finances de X » est une université dont le sujet d'étude est exclusivement les finances de X, pas une université qui étudie la finance en général. Il [semblerait](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Universit%C3%A9+des+finances%22&gws_rd=ssl#q=%22Universit%C3%A9+des+finances%22&start=10) que « université des finances » soit une traduction courante (je la vois appliquée à des institutions polonaises, russes et chinoises) de ce que l'on appellerait proprement en français une *faculté de finance* ou une *école de finance*.

Comment: Très judicieuse réponse, je me suis posé la même question, bien que les différences pluriel/singulier constituent souvent un sujet linguistique difficile à mon sens.

Answer (score 4):

Merci de discuter cette étrange traduction.
Je partage l'opinion de Gilles.

Je fais partie de cette université. Il y a longtemps, une enseignante très expérimentée me disait que "pri Pravitelstve" n'équivaut pas à "auprès de" (ex.: ouvrir un compte auprès d'une banque).
Je ne saurais pas expliquer le degré de la participation du gouvernement russe à l'existence de l'université.
Je vous sais gré pour m'avoir soufflé de changer "près le" contre "auprès de".
Par contre j'insistais toujours sur le singulier de "finance". Il ne s'agit pas des finances d'une structure concrète, mais de la science "finance" et de tout ce qui tourne autour.
Bref, je dirais qu'on est plutôt Grande école (ou École supérieure) de finance de Moscou.

Merci à tous les Français maîtrisant bien leur langue d'avoir réfléchi sur nous.